How to Open the Default Phone App Scene from CarPlay Scene on iOS (Including Devices Without Multiple Scene Support)?
I’m developing an iOS app with CarPlay support, and I’m trying to open the default phone app scene from the CarPlay scene. This needs to work on all iOS devices, including those that do not support multiple scenes (e.g., older iOS versions or devices that do not have multiple windows).
Scenario:
•   The default configuration scene is the phone app, and the CarPlay scene is a separate one.
•   When interacting with the CarPlay interface, I want to programmatically switch or launch the phone app scene.

I’ve found resources on managing multiple scenes on devices that support it, but not much about how to handle this scenario for devices that only support a single scene.
Could someone guide me on the correct approach to achieve this behavior in Objective-C?
I’d appreciate code examples that work on all iOS devices, including handling cases where multiple scenes aren’t available.
Here’s a rough version of what I’m trying, but I’m unsure how to make this compatible across all devices:
- (void)switchToPhoneAppScene {
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        NSSet<UIScene *> *connectedScenes = [UIApplication sharedApplication].connectedScenes;
        
        for (UIScene *scene in connectedScenes) {
            if ([scene.session.role isEqualToString:UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication]) {
                // Trying to activate the phone app scene
                [UIApplication.sharedApplication requestSceneSessionActivation:scene.session
                                                                        userActivity:nil
                                                                      options:nil
                                                                    errorHandler:nil];
                return;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // For iOS versions below 13 that do not support multiple scenes
        // What should be done here to ensure compatibility?
    }
}

What would be the best way to handle scene activation or app switching across all iOS devices, regardless of whether they support multiple scenes?
Thanks in advance!

I would drop support for < iOS 13.  You can probably reasonably drop support for < iOS 15
